# $_FILES or $_POST inside of function

Tags: php

Do i have to pass $_FILES['image'] as a argument or can i simply put $_FILES['image'] in the function?

Below i haven't put $_FILES['image'] as an argument.  Is this bad practice or do i have to pass it as an argument?
e.g.

```
   function image() {
    if (@getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']==false)) {
    //no valid image
    } elseif(isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size']>512000) {
    //image too big

    } else {
//success
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are [superglobals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). It is expected that you access them as global variables.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quote from the [official info-source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) :

> Note:
>
> This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply
>   means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is
>   no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions or
>   methods.

In other words, since it is **superglobal**, you don't have to pass it as an argument anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`$_FILES` and `$_POST` are *superglobals*. They're predefined by the language and are available everywhere.